# Single Page Web Apps for the iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, html, jqtouch, sencha-touch

I'm looking to make a single-page web app that works exclusively on the iPad, like [Gmail on the iPad](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/04/gmail-on-ipad.html) and the [iPad User Guide](http://help.apple.com/ipad/mobile/interface/). An app like this must be made using a framework that allow web pages to behave in ways much more akin to iPad's native applications (momentum scrolling, split-view panes, UIKit-style interface), but done completely in HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript (with WebKit and Safari extensions like iOS-specific multi-touch and gesture events).

The only public framework I've found that targets the iPad in this matter is Sencha Touch. Naturally, Google and Apple aren't sharing the libraries *they've* written (ie. PastryKit, AdLib, etc). Are there any others (the open-source *only* license for Sencha Touch is prohibitive, and jQTouch is *only* for small-screen devices like the iPhone 4, and *not* the iPad)? How would I go about writing momentum scrolling and split-view panes like this? Any good resources/tutorials/books/links on these advanced topics?

For a lot of reasons, people want to write web apps for the iPad that can compete with native.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'd have to do it yourself.  The sencha touch commercial license is free, so you won't have to open up your own code.  On the iPad it looks really good.

You can also use PhoneGap to put a native wrapper around it so most users won't notice it's a web app.

Jquery mobile is also an option but it doesn't look as good as sencha, IMHO

- [Sencha Touch license](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/license/)
- [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Also checkout App Titanium... You develop in Javascript, but it renders your app as native code...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SproutCore and:

- http://blog.sproutcore.com/post/531215199/introducing-sproutcore-touch
- http://touch.sproutcore.com/hedwig/
- http://www.npr.org/webapp